# Status show SSL is in use even though I did not set up certificate on the client side?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ssl

I want to set up SSL connections to a distant MariaDB server. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-setup-mariadb-ssl-and-secure-connections-from-clients/). I generated the certificate for the server, restarted it, and got this:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                                           |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| have_openssl        | YES                                             |
| have_ssl            | YES                                             |
| ssl_ca              | /var/packages/MariaDB10/etc/ssl/ca-cert.pem     |
| ssl_capath          |                                                 |
| ssl_cert            | /var/packages/MariaDB10/etc/ssl/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher          |                                                 |
| ssl_crl             |                                                 |
| ssl_crlpath         |                                                 |
| ssl_key             | /var/packages/MariaDB10/etc/ssl/server-key.pem  |
| version_ssl_library | OpenSSL 1.0.2r-fips  26 Feb 2019                |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I also generated the client certificate. However, to make sure I understand the process, I proceeded step by step, and did not install them. I first changed the user settings to `REQUIRE SSL`. Then

```
mysql --user=user --password=password
```

fails with a

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'host' (using password: YES)
```

So far so good. However,

```
mysql --user=user --password=password --ssl
```

succeeds, even though I did not provide any client certificate. `status` shows

```
SSL:                    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

which, if I understand correctly, means that the connection is indeed using SSL. How is that possible, is it the expected behavior?

I am using MariaDB 10.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[REQURE SSL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/#tls-options) only requires a TLS connection. Use `REQUIRE X509` to enforce a TLS client certificate, or better, use `REQUIRE SUBJECT` or `REQUIRE ISSUER` to ensure that is the identical certificate that matches the one issued.